# Run a java web app on Tomcat outside Eclipse on Windows

Tags: tomcat

I developped a small web application using Java in Eclipse which have this structure:

> Search.java (the servlet)
>
> index.jsp
>
> results.jsp

ervlet => Run as => run on server ) , the servlet calls index.jsp, takes the user input from it, does some processing and then displays the results on results.jsp

So far, it works fine on Eclipse, even on the browser when I type: localhost:8080/MyApp/search  (which calls the servlet)

Now I want to run my program without Eclipse: I want to start TomcatServer outside eclipse and then type the link on the browser. I put my **.war** file in **apache-tomcat-8.0.43\webapps** and restarted the server (using **apache-tomcat-8.0.43\bin\startup.bat**)

The problem is that when I type **localhost:8080/MyApp/search** on the browser I get a **404 error**. Basically, the links works only when I run Tomcat from Eclipse. Besides, it seems that startup.bat works fine (**http://localhost:8080**/ is correct).

Is there a solution so I can run my Tomcat server and then my app without Eclipse?

I am using Eclipse EE Neon, Tomcat 8, Windows and Chrome as browser.

Comment: Run your tomcat server and then use the admin console to deploy the .war at localhost:8080. After deploying the war you can click the name in the gui and it will take you to the context root for that web application. I think deploying it like this it usually uses the artifact name as a context root as default so it might be different from the address you had when deploying it in eclipse.

Comment: What is the name of your WAR file?

Comment: the name on the War file in webapps directory is MyApp but the artifact is MyApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Thanks a lot, I could run it now. Actually, I deployed the WAR file wrongly, I just copy paste it in webapps. I solve it by deploying it with the admin console and checking the name

Comment: If you add <build><finalName>MyApp.war</finalName>...</build> to your pom.xml then your copy/paste deployment will work as expected. Don't forget to undeploy from the management console the first time you try it though.